# Ftp Url With space in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

I cant access to the this ftp url with the apple ftpsample:

```
ftp://192.168.1.20/Lavori/Andrea Baccin/
```

the space in the name of the folder make a "Invalid URL" error

if i can encode the url with:

```
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

that make me this error:

```
[CALayer appendBytes:length:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x184890
```

some help?

Thankyou guys!

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your url object is not an NSString at runtime. Have you tried debugging this line ?

here is a working sample code :

```
NSString *url = @"ftp://192.168.1.20/Lavori/Andrea Baccin/";
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

The console shows :

> [Session started at 2011-02-02
>   14:23:48 +0100.] 2011-02-02
>   14:23:51.515 UISpec[669:207]
>   ftp://192.168.1.20/Lavori/Andrea%20Baccin/

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: doesn't work! 
the problem is whitespaces in url! ftp://192.168.1.20/Lavori/ work fine

Comment: Your url object is not an instance of NSString. I edited my answer with a working code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your error is not related to

```
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I think you have some items the overreleased. Recheck your code on memory management issues, or post more source code here.